# #DocuSignAPI Two signers in an embedded workflow using SOAP API

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, docusignapi

I am trying to set up a process where I have an in-person signer as a first signer in an embedded document, and the signing host as a second signer in the same embedded process.

My process is calling the `createenvelope()` method in the wsdl and creating the envelope, and launching in an embedded frame for the first in-person signer.  After my first signer signs, the embedded process ends, and my second signer (the captive host) doesn't get to sign.

I think I need to make a second call to view the envelope again in an embedded frame as a second signer.  I see the restapi/envelopes/{envelope}/recipient/view endpoint in the rest api, and I was looking for something equivalent in the SOAP wsdl.  Has anyone completed a 2 - person embedded process calling SOAP endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you'll need to make a second API call for the second embedded signer.. you'll want to make the **RequestRecipientToken()** API call if using SOAP.  Check out [THIS PAGE](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Embedding%20Group/Pre-DocuSign%20Operations.htm#Requesti) of the SOAP API guide for more info and an example.